# IDisposable: How dispose works with Autofac

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose

So let's assume that I register an object like this:

```
builder.Register<IFoo>().AsSingleInstance<Foo>()
```

Now let's assume that `Foo` implements `IDisposable`:

```
public class Foo: IDisposable
{
  void Dispose()
  {
    // do something
  };
}
```

When I call `Foo.Dispose()` inside the lifetime of the container does it signals CG to clear up the object? Generally is IDisposable simply there as a general guideline on how to handle unmanaged resources with no behind the scenes logic(other than for example working together with the `using` keyword)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but what I mainly wanted was about how a container and CG interact with one another if someone calls manually the `Dispose` method inside the container. Generally an explanation about how IDisposable works behind the scenes.

What I found out after researching it a bit more is that `IDisposable` does not interact with the container or/and CG in any way. So if you call the `Dispose` of an object inside a container as long as there is a reference to that object it will not be garbage collected. So in the end you can call multiple times the same `Dispose` method without any issue regardless if it's in a container and simply `Autofac` will call it once more (you can of course disable autofac from calling dispose if you dont want to)

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to read this https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html ?

p.s. I don't have enough reputation that's why I added the answer instead of comment the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement `IDisposable` interface.
Autofac can automatically dispose of some components, but you have the ability to manually specify a disposal mechanism, too.

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
            .As<IFoo>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

for more info [Autofac Dispose](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html)